# Split files on the basis of length

Tags: shell, split

I have a file,the total length of the file should be 454  for one row.
Any character after 454 should move in the next row  .

After `col5` the length is 454, i need that from `col1` it should move to the next line

Input file:

```
col1col2col3col4col5col1col2col3col4col5col1col2col3
```

Expected Output file:

```
col1col2col3col4col5
col1col2col3col4col5
col1col2col3
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a 'hard' break at 454 character, use `fold` command:

```
fold -w 454 file
```

If your input file contains text, and you don't want to break words, use `fmt` command:

```
fmt -w 454 file
```

Comment: `fold` also has the option `-s`, breaking on a space.

Answer (score 0):

Its not splitting the whole length into 454 characters each.

0064208520010012009070199991231459 GRACE AVE                                                                                                           PANAMA CITY        FL324012756  BAY                     8502156007                                      CREDENTIALING@FLATHERAPY.COM             NYpanama c001    I0         0            1    17530101                                                                                                       *U*00656812600200120090701999912312215 BURDETT AVE                                                                                                        TROY               NY121802466  RENSSELAER              5182713300              5182713681              CREDENTIALING@FLATHERAPY.COM              YYtroy    001    I0         0            1    17530101                                                                                                        U

Here you can see U is the end of the first row and then the new row starts . So i Want that 0065  line should come in the next line.

Fold and fmt command are not working correctly

Comment: What does `fold  -w 20 inputfile` show with the inputfile given in your question?

Comment: This should be an edit to the question, not an answer.

Comment: Also, note that we can only comply with requirements *included in the question itself*. If an answer works for the data you gave in the question, consider accepting that answer as correct and then asking a new question that better describes your real requirements.